# Добавление обработчика вызова произвольной пользовательской функции

Tags: javascript

У меня тут возникла интересная задачка.

Что требуется...
Мне необходимо реализовать функцию, которая могла бы навесить обработчик до и/или после выполнения какой-либо **ПРОИЗВОЛЬНОЙ** пользовательской функции...

**Например:** 
Вывод записи в лог после вызова функции

```
afterFunction(someUserFunction, function(){
    console.log("Была вызвана функция " + someUserFunction.toString());
});
```

Соответственно, после вызова `someUserFunction()` в лог, должна быть выведена запись о вызове данной функции.

Также в качестве примера может быть вычисление времени выполнения какой-либо функции...

Мне **не нужно** перехватывать параметры и результат ответа.
Просто нужно добавить пару обработчиков на выполнение переданной функции.

Есть какие-нибудь рабочие варианты?
Если нет, то также можете обосновать это в ответе.

**UPDATE 1**:

- Вариант с прописать колбеки непосредственно в параметрах необходимой функции не рассматривается.
- Целевая функция может быть произвольной.
- Целевая функция должна передаваться в виде параметра.
- Соответственно, функция которая навешивает обработчик понятия не имеет какая целевая функция к ней прилетит.

**UPDATE 2**:

- После всех манипуляций, вызов функции должен остаться в прежнем виде, поэтому вариант с фасадом также не подходит .

**UPDATE 3**:

Попытки переопределения функции я также предпринимал. И откровенно говоря, это было ближе всего к тому, что мне нужно, однако, с этим у меня тоже возникли некие проблемы.

Переопределение работает в данном случае:

```
var a = function(){ console.log("original function"); };
a();
var old = a;
a = function(){ 
    console.log("handler"); 
    old(); 
};
a();
```

Но мне этого мало... и при попытке перенести все это дело в функцию, которая и будет навешивать произвольный обработчик к произвольной функции все перестает работать.

Данный код уже не работает:

```
var a = function(){console.log("original function")};
a();
var redefine = function(someFunction, someHandler){
    var old = someFunction;
    someFunction = function(){console.log("handler");old();};
}
redefine(a, function(){console.log("my handler")});
a();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учтите, что функция, которую Вы хотите переопределить, должна быть глобально-видима.

```js
var oldAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {
  console.log("before - ", msg);
  oldAlert(msg);
  console.log("after - ", msg);
}
alert("test");
```

Comment: да, спасибо! комментарий о глобальной видимости все решил)

Answer (score 1):

Дописать функции два дополнительных необязательных параметра, которые могут принимать значения колбэков. Проверять в функции: если параметр является функцией, то выполнить её.

```js
const notMyFunction = function(a,b) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(a+b);
}

const myLogFasade = function(someFunction, onBefore, onAfter) {
  if (typeof onBefore === 'function') {
    onBefore();
  }

  if (typeof someFunction === 'function') {
    someFunction();
  }

  if (typeof onAfter === 'function') {
    onAfter();
  }
}

// Просто выполнение
notMyFunction(2,3);

// с событиями
myLogFasade(
  function() {
    notMyFunction(20,30);
  },
  function() {
    console.log('before action');
  },
  function() {
    console.log('after action');
  }
);
```

Comment: так и я могу... в том то и соль, что объявлял эти функции не я.

Comment: @МихаилРебров переделал

Comment: с фасадом я также знаком и данный вариант также не подойдет, потому что при вызове `notMyFunction(2,3);` не произойдёт никаких событий, кроме выполнения оригинальной функции.

Comment: я не в обиду и не из вредности) я и сам немного поломал голову перед тем как закинуть вопрос сюда... на `ruby` и на `Java` я знаю как это сделать...А в JS я не настолько прямо сказать силен) и не уверен что это вообще возможно.

Comment: Понял, что имелось в виду. Можете "перезаписать" оригинальную функцию https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136522/can-you-alter-a-javascript-function-after-declaring-it и добавить логирование. Тогда дальше по скрипту все вызовы будут выполнять уже вашу функцию

Comment: да я думал в данную сторону, но у меня почему то не переопределялась функция...может где-то накосячил конечно или что-то проглядел...
я сейчас посмотрю ответ по присланной Вами ссылке, если он подойдёт, то  можете оформить ответ - я вам хоть плюсик за старания поставлю...но лучше подождать наверное)

Comment: я обновил вопрос.

Comment: решающих оказался комментарий Игоря о глобальной видимости, тем не менее Вы также, по-моему заработали свой плюсик. Спасибо за участие!